# Slow boot 19.10 and errors during shutdown

Tags: boot, mount, 19.10, systemd, nfs

Can someone please explain what the test.mount service does during boot? Why is it taking such a long time and how do I solve this slow boot up? System specs:

- kubuntu 19.10
- ssd samsung 860 evo containing kubuntu with lvm2

With al other drives disconnected stil a slow boot. This is happening since a couple of days. During shutdown the following error message are displayed:

```
sd-umount[3030] failed to unmount /oldroot: Device or resource busy. 
sd-umount[3031]....etc
sd-umount[3032]....etc
sd-umount[3033]....etc
```

The following command `systemd-analyze blame` outputs:

```
    1min 30.018s test.mount
          6.797s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
          2.852s e2scrub_reap.service
          1.818s udisks2.service
          1.320s lvm2-pvscan@8:1.service
          1.161s mnt-243EA2013EA1CC5C.mount
          1.116s dev-mapper-vgkubuntu\x2droot.device
           857ms snapd.service
           778ms snap-boa-196.mount
           759ms snap-core18-1650.mount
           684ms snap-xonotic-49.mount
           680ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d28\x2d1804-110.mount
           614ms snap-core-8592.mount
           577ms snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1353.mount
           516ms snap-core-8689.mount
           478ms dev-loop5.device
           470ms snap-chromium-1040.mount
           454ms dev-loop8.device
           447ms snap-urban\x2dterror-18.mount
           440ms mpd.service
           431ms firewalld.service
           416ms dev-loop3.device
           407ms dev-loop2.device
           395ms systemd-journal-flush.service
           386ms postfix@-.service
           382ms dev-loop9.device
           365ms systemd-logind.service
           357ms snap-termius\x2dapp-38.mount
```

Output of `sudo systemd-analyze critical-chain` :

```
The time when unit became active or started is printed after the "@" character.
The time the unit took to start is printed after the "+" character.

graphical.target @1min 38.750s
└─sddm.service @1min 38.746s +3ms
  └─systemd-user-sessions.service @1min 38.711s +9ms
    └─network.target @1.886s
      └─NetworkManager.service @1.858s +27ms
        └─network-pre.target @1.856s
          └─firewalld.service @1.424s +431ms
            └─polkit.service @1.543s +9ms
              └─basic.target @1.350s
                └─sockets.target @1.350s
                  └─snapd.socket @1.350s +409us
                    └─sysinit.target @1.344s
                      └─swap.target @1.343s
                        └─dev-mapper-vgkubuntu\x2dswap_1.swap @1.296s +27ms
                          └─dev-mapper-vgkubuntu\x2dswap_1.device @1.296s
```

I already have tried the boot repair utility and have run a filesystem check with a live usb. The file system check with gparted showed no error, however it did finish whitin a couple of seconds. Is that normal to?

fstab shows:

```
/dev/mapper/vgkubuntu-root /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
/dev/mapper/vgkubuntu-swap_1 none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/243EA2013EA1CC5C /mnt/243EA2013EA1CC5C rw,auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/869116c1-0c87-4df6-a38d-269d2f8df038 /mnt/869116c1-0c87-4df6-a38d-269d2f8df038 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
192.168.1.107:/test /test  nfs      defaults    0       0
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your `/etc/fstab` for existence of `/test` mount point.

It looks like you have a remote file share that your system tries to mount at boot, but it could not be available, so mounting of unavailable share takes so much time.

Also, check your partitions file types and mount types in `/etc/fstab`.

- Edit your `/etc/fstab` and add `noauto` option to your `/test` mountpoint.
- Create a script, for example ( `~/scripts/mounttest.sh`):

  `#!/bin/bash`
  `/usr/bin/sleep 180 && /usr/bin/mount /test`
- Give it execution permission: `chmod +x ~/scripts/mounttest.sh`

Add it to crontab: `sudo crontab -e`

```
@reboot /home/user/scripts/mounttest.sh
```

It should start mounting task when system is already loaded, so no boot wait should be present because of it.

Comment: Ok so the slow boot up was caused by a remote mount (named test) which was not available because it exists on a NAS device that was offline due to a power outage. Kinda strange that it will influence the bootup process  of the OS. Is that specific to (k)ubuntu?

Comment: After some more searching I came across a forum that described the same error messages during shutdown. That person was able to trace the problem to a systemd update. After he downgraded the error was gone. https://forum.manjaro.org/t/sd-umount-failed-to-unmount-oldroot/102412/6 Anyone experienced the same thing? My current version is  242-7ubuntu3.7.

Comment: @magician1981 Updated answer

Comment: Your script works. Many thanks. I expect that an update for systemd will solve the other problem.